# What's the meaning of "magic" pragma in nim?

Tags: nim-lang

When going through the code in Nim project itself, I find that some proc decorated by "magic" pragma misses proc definition ([example](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/master/lib/core/macros.nim#L282)). There's no doc to explain the pragma, I guess the proc's definition is somewhere else and is merged while compiling.But I cannot still find the definition by searching the whole project.

Do I misunderstand the "magic" pragma? What's the meaning of it? And how to use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `{.magic.}` pragma is used to define built-in operations and types, i.e. anything that requires compiler magic in order to work (hence the name). It is not intended to be used outside the system modules.

Comment: Where can I get the definitions of these procs?

Comment: They are all implemented in the compiler. For example, the procedure that you linked to is eventually implemented in the `opcParseStmtToAst` branch in the `rawExecute()` procedure in `compiler/vm.nim`.

Comment: In some other languages/VMs, these `magic` operations are also called `intrinsics`.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function for additional context.